# How to use/render unicode characters correctly to config bash prompt using $PS1?

Tags: linux, bash, unicode, terminal, prompt

I have the following as my PS1 setup for my bash prompt. But when I type very long command into terminal, the line does not wrap well (it continues from the same line instead of starting a new line).

```
BROWN='\[\e[38;5;5m\]'
ARROW=$'\xe2\x86\x92'
RESET='\[\e[m\]'
export PS1="[\u@\h \w] $BROWN$ARROW $RESET"
```

I want to code in this style as in future I may have more colors and symbols for more interesting and complex prompt, so that using variables is a preferred way for me.

But even I write PS1 in the most straightforward way (without variables) as follows, the line wrap is still wrong.

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \w] \[\e[38;5;5m\]→ \[\e[m\]"
```

I think the problem should come from the use of unicode characters, because if I set up PS1 with no use of unicode character as below (with unicode arrow char replaced by `$`), there is no wrapping issue at all.

```
export PS1="[\u@\h \w] \[\e[38;5;5m\]\$ \[\e[m\]"
```

For more information, my bash version is 4.2.46 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) and the terminal renders the unicode character that I want to use fine (with `echo -e '\xe2\x86\x92'`).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What terminal and font are you using?

Comment: @MaximilianBallard window's terminal and cascadia code pl.

Comment: @pynexj all except LC_ALL is "C".

Comment: Bash thinks `ARROW` prints three characters. You can wrap it with `\[...\]` to force a particular width (say `ARROW=$'\xe2\\[\x86\x92\\]'` if the glyph it prints is one character wide) but that's obviously a hack. This is a duplicate anyway - let me look for the previous similar question.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `BROWN="\[\e[38;5;5m\]"` (double quotes) yet?